# How to get parameter value from Object[]

Tags: c#

```
    //SqlParameter
public static SqlParameter[] SetParameter(string strconn, string spName, Hashtable ht)
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameters = GetSpParameterSet(strconn, spName);

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ht.ContainsKey(parameters[i].ParameterName))
                {
                    if (parameters[i].Direction != ParameterDirection.Output)
                    {
                        parameters[i].Value = ht[parameters[i].ParameterName];
                    }
                }
            }
            return parameters;
        }
```

Usage

```
object[] param;
ht.Add("@p1", strSearch.ToString());
ht.Add("@p2", Info.Email);
ht.Add("@p3", "some value");
ht.Add("@p4", RoleID);
ht.Add("@p5", strlocation);Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
param = SqlHelperParameterCache.SetParameter(ParameterCollector.GetConString(), "StoredProcedure1", ht);
```

I have the above code snippet and need to get the value of a parameter.

If i try    `string m = param.GetValue(4).ToString();` i only get the name of the parameter but i want the parameter value.

Comment: What is result of SetParameter method? I guess you dont have such code snippet -HashTable initiation is not in the place.

Comment: @Reniuz, i have edited the post, it return SqlParameter[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `param` is an instance of [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string m = (param.Value ?? "").ToString();
```

If `param` is `SqlParameter[]` then you need to index into the array and *then* query the value

```
string m = (param[4].Value ?? "").ToString();
```

Comment: Symbol 'Value' in (param[4].Value ?? "").ToString() is not resolved.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior is `param` `object[]` or `SqlParameter[]`? Seens like it's `object[]` - if that's the case just cast `param[4]` to `SqlParameter` then you can access `Value`.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior then as per my previous comment, you need to cast the `object` to `SqlParameter` e.g. `(param[4] as SqlParameter).Value`.